# Unable to change primary color completely in foundation 5 rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

I created a new rails 4 app with foundation 5 (via foundation-rails gem). Now I'm about to change some styles.

If I change the primary color of the page inside `foundation_and_overrides.scss` by enabling and changing the line:

```
$primary-color: #0f6f5f;
```

the result is, that all links are now using the new color, but the buttons still use the old foundation blue as background.
Digging into foundation scss I can see that the default background color of a button is $primary-color, so why isn't it changing it's color?

How do I change the default background for all buttons using foundation 5 without using something like

```
.button {
    background-color: #0f6f5f !important;
}
```

which has 2 disadvantages:

- it also changes the background color for buttons of other classes like .secondary
- I would have to apply such style to many other elements/classes I'm not aware of for now as well, if foundation doesn't let me change primary-color correctly.

**Update:** I found out that this also holds for other elements. Changing e.g.

```
$body-font-family: "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
```

will change the font for simple text in the body, but not for buttons, forms etc. even if those font-families are defined like

```
$button-font-family: $body-font-family;
```

inside foundation.

So something in my logic must be completely wrong. How to customize a foundation absed rails app??

Comment: Are you sure that Sass code is correct?  The # is missing in your color declaration.

Comment: sorry, that was a SO-typo, not copied from actual code! Good point anyway - I fixed it in the post. As said, it does change the color for links etc., but not for button background.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 possibilities why it happened for you:

- First, you might have set default button color somewhere and it overwrites the `$primary-color` that you have set. Inspect the button to see if the color is overwritten or not.
- Second, in the file that defines style for button, see the first line if it `@import` the file that has customized settings for `$primary-color`

For example in my project, all the default settings are in `_global.scss` file, all the customized settings are in `_settings.scss` file. So if I wanna to change settings for any element, I have to `@import` the file that has customized settings. Hope it works for you.